# Make predictive mode default emacs

Tags: emacs, auctex, auto-completion

Every time I fire up Emacs, I run `M-x predictive-mode`. Is there a way to automate that and preferably while editing TeX.

Comment: Put it in your `.emacs` file. If you want it just for TeX I think there's a `tex-mode-hook` that will do the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding

```
(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'predictive-mode)
```

to your `.emacs` file should be enough to turn it on everywhere (leave a comment if you don't know what this is).

If you want it only on latex-mode, do this instead:

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'predictive-mode)
```

Comment: Simple predictive mode didn't work, but the one with hook did.

Comment: @rafee Fixed the "everywhere" version, in case anyone comes looking.